# How to Write/ Edit a txt file using Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am in the beginning of Android App learning phase. I have a .txt file in my assets folder consisting of strings in each line, like this-

```
AWOL    JJ  AWOL
Aaronic JJ  Aaronic
Aaronical   JJ  Aaronical
```

What I want to do is just replace `JJ` with `NN` and keep rest the same. My questions are-

1. Is there a way to edit the already existing file, because all the solutions I found are talking about creating some other file using function `File(<filename>)`?
2. If I follow the solutions described on different websites, I can not access the file USING `File()`, it shows the error that the `file can not be found` even though I have created an empty file with the same name. I can not access the file if it is inside `assets` folder or inside `app/src`. So, instead I am using `Context.assets.open(<filename>)` for readin the orginal file which opens the file as `inputstream`. Although I don't know any other way of opening the file using `File()` for writing.

```
// FOR READING FROM ORIGINAL FILE
var inputStreamLemmDict = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(context!!.assets.open("my_file.dict"))).readLines()

// FOR WRITING TO ANOTHER FILE
File("path_to/my_file.txt").bufferedWriter().use { out ->
        inputStreamLemmDict.forEach {
            var eachLineSplit = it.split("\\s".toRegex())
            if (eachLineSplit[1] == "NNN") {
                out.write("${eachLineSplit[0]}\tNN\t${eachLineSplit[2]}\n")
            }
            else {
            out.write("${it}\n")
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you can't edit your APK contents form itself. Therefore, if the file is in assets - you can't edit it.

Comment: okay, so where should I place the files for editing?. I read about putting them in `app/src`

Comment: that's up to you where to put it. On external or internal storage.

Comment: okay, so how would you proceed with this problem of writing?. Where would you have placed the file?

Comment: also if you only want to replace `JJ` with `NN`, it is much easier to use `String.replace("JJ","NN")` (that is java, not kotlin, I know, but it should not be a problem to convert)

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the file (except just editting it)

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly but I just can not make changes to the file.

Comment: Once this file is written I want to place it back in assets. This editing of file is one time only. It is me doing it, not the user of the app.

Comment: you can't place it back in assets, as I already said - assets are part of APK, and you can't edit APK

Comment: I could cut/copy/paste files manually that are in assets or other folders.

Comment: Android application is assembled int the APK, which contains your compiled sources, assets and other things. **APK can not be modified** from the app itself. You can only read from it, not write into it.

Comment: When you install APK there are no assets folders anywhere, assets are part of APK.

Comment: Please pass some basic android tutorials before you continue. It looks like you are missing android basics.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following solution to achieve your desired result.

UPDATE : Please try this solution to read file from assets and get your result. This solution is not tested.

Make sure yourfilename.txt is under assets folder.

```
try {
val inputStream:InputStream = assets.open("yourfilename.txt")
      val text = inputStream.bufferedReader().use{it.readText()}

        println(text)
        text = text.replace("JJ".toRegex(), "NN")
        f.writeText(text)
}catch (e:Exception){
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, thanks for the answer. This sounds reasonable, but the problem is the `File(file)`, I can not access the `file` by giving the path to it here, which is required by `File` function. SO, my question is where should I place this `file`, in which folder of android studio, so that I can access it by giving the path

Comment: What is `f` here in `f.writeText`?

Comment: I am sorry that was from old solution. Please check if new solution by @markB works.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var lineNumber = 0
var newString = ""
File("src/dataFile").forEachLine {
    ++lineNumber
    println("$lineNumber: $it")
    newString = it.replace("JJ", "NN")
    println("New string : $newString")
}
File("src/dataFile").writeText(newString) 
}
```